# Dynamic allocation and Segmentation fault in shell C

Tags: c, shell, malloc

I want to dynamic allocate memory for line and argv and realloc if needed but i get errors when i do it like this:

`char* argv = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER);` assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast in many lines like strcmp. Error log : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UopWE.jpg

Also i want it to print nothing than $(space) when someone hits ENTER but i get Segmentation fault(Core dumped) with the code or not  `scanf("%s",line); if(line == "\n") printf("$ ");`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `argv` should be an argument to `main`. The usual function head of `main` with parameters is `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or the equivalent `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: If this is not what you want to do, give `argv` another name. Whenever I see a variable named `argv` I expect it to be declared as I wrote, cause that's the convention.

Comment: @Δημήτρης Γαλάνης  It seems it is not this declaration  char* argv = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER);  that invokes the error. In some part of the code you are trying to use something like argv[i[ and to compare it with a string.

Comment: I did int main(int argc, char *argv1[]) and still get segmentation fault

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the program, except for the missing error check for `execve` failure.  (The name `argv` is not reserved or anything like that, so it's just confusing to use it as a variable.)

Comment: `argv` is the name you use for parameters you send to the program. In general, you do not change the content in the program. If you have `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and you call the program like this: `./a.out Hello World!` then `argc`=3, `argv[0]`="a.out", `argv[1]`="Hello" and `argv[2]`="World!"

Comment: @Δημήτρης Γαλάνης  You showed irrelevant code. Show the code where the declaration with the dynamic allocation is used.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow is  char* arg = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER); the correct way to do it ? Because i get incompatible assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast.

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΓαλάνης it seems you need to allocate an array of pointers something like  char ** argv = malloc( N * sizeof(char *)); where N is some value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current code, `argv` is a array of pointers, but it the proposed code `char* argv = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER);` it becomes an array of **characters**.

When you later try to do `argv[i]=token;`, you try to assign a pointer (`token`) to a mere character, which causes the warning *assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast*.

The correct way is to let `argv` still be a pointer to pointers:

```
int cmd_argc = 10;
char **argv = malloc(cmd_argc * sizeof(char *));
```

If you later need more parameters in `argv` array, you will be able to realloc:

```
cmd_argc *= 2;
if (NULL == realloc(argv, cmd_argc * sizeof(char *))) {
    // memory allocation error
    ...
}
```

But *by convention*, `argc` and `argv` are used for the parameters of the current program, so you should use another name like for example `cmd_argv`.

Comment: char** arg = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER) worked ! How can i implement that if user types enter another line with prompt is displayed.When i press enter it says Segmenation fault (core dumped).

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΓαλάνης: Ask a new question with the exact code causing the error and just a reference to this one.

Answer (score 2):

If this

```
char* argv = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER);
```

results in an *assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast* warning, the actual code you are compiling probably misses an

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

directive at the start of the file.  GCC still implements implicit function definitions (long removed from the C standard), so it automatically supplies a declaration of `malloc` like this:

```
int malloc();
```

But this is definition is useless on 64-bit architectures because it clips to upper 32 bits of the pointer value (casting the return value back to `char *` will not restore them).

Current versions of GCC will warn about the missing declaration of `malloc`.  You really should compile with `-Wall` to get this warning (it was not enabled by default with older GCC versions).

Comment: It says `arg` in the error message, not `argv`, as in the code you posted.

Comment: I changed it so it isnt the same with main . I will edit my post.

Comment: Please double-check that you actually have `char* arg[50];` in your code and not `char arg[50];` instead.